# 2010 15" MacBook Pro unable to recognize internal display, works fine with external

Tags: macbook-pro, display, logicboard

Today I walked over to my 15" Mid-2010 MacBook Pro (which I had been controlling via VNC not long before) and attempted to use it. I was greeted with a screen that would not wake up.

After much rebooting (by holding down the power button and over SSH), I plugged it into an external monitor, logged in, and opened up `System Information` (formerly `System Profiler`). To my shock and horror, only the external monitor was detected and the internal "Color LCD" wasn't listed.

Does anyone know anything about the pathology of a problem like this? Does fixing something like this (probably) entail a logic board replacement?

I'm inclined to believe that the problem lies somewhere in an LCD controller or power supply rather than the panel (because I'd assume that a broken panel would still show up).

Again, the general functions of the machine work just fine—just not the internal display.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar symptoms on my MBP 13 (mid-2010). Internal display died suddenly and external display worked fine. None of the software or startup tricks did not bring the life back to in-built screen.
Disconnecting and re-connecting the battery connector from the logic board fixed this problem.

Here is the instruction:
https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2010+Display+Replacement/4293#s7329

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem on my MBP 13 (mid-2012) which i solved buy doing this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7GlETDBybqI&t=1s